# Is $\sin( | z^{2}| )$ ,where z is complex, analytic?

Tags: complex-analysis

I know sin is analytic, but I got myself confused in regards to the $| z^{2}| $. I want to say it is since any input sin takes is fine but I feel there's something I missed.

Thanks.

Comment: Can a bounded nonconstant function on $\mathbb{C}$ be analytic?  You are talking about complex-analytic functions, right?

Comment: Yes. I thought it is analytic in U where U $\subset $ Dom(f)...

Comment: Sorry, I'm confused. My sources state that sin(z) is entire but it is bounded and nonconstant... From your response it sounds like those two properties can't exist for an analytic function.

Comment: sin(z) is unbounded as the imaginary part goes to +/- infinity.

Answer (score 6):

The function
$$f(z):=\sin\bigl(|z|^2\bigr)$$
is real for all $z\in{\mathbb C}$. When written in the form $f(x+i y)=u(x,y)+i v(x,y)$ this implies $$v_x(x,y)\equiv v_y(x,y)\equiv0\ .$$
If $f$ were analytic then by the CR equations we would have $$u_x(x,y)\equiv u_y(x,y)\equiv0$$ as well, or $f={\rm const.}$ But $f(0)=0\ne1=f\bigl(\sqrt{\pi/2}\bigr)$.

Answer (score 2):

Note that ,  $|z^2|$ is real , and so $\sin(|z^2|)$ is bounded. If $\sin(|z^2|)$ is entire then it will be constant........contradiction.

Comment: I think I get it. So differentiable only when Im(z)=0?

Answer (score 1):

*Alternatively:* If $f$ is analytic then $f$ must satisfy the Cauchy-Riemann equations, one form of which is

$$\frac{\partial f}{\partial \bar z} = 0$$

As $|z^2| = |z|^2 = z\bar z$, we have  $$ \frac{\partial f}{\partial \bar z} = z \cos(z\bar z) \neq 0$$